# jQuery Tabs "common" markup

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a number of jQuery UI Tab divs. Is there any way to have markup that is common to all of the tab / divs? Specifically, I would like to add save and cancel buttons but really the markup could contain anything.

I can duplicate these across all my tabs if needed or simply add the markup within the outer div and give it some negative margin (moving it to within all of the tab areas.

Comment: Why not just put it in the outer div as you've already suggested? That's probably how I'd do it if I were going to.

Comment: If you put it in the outer div that is part of the tab, it is not rendered. Putting the content in a div that is not part of the tab structure and then adding negative margin works.

Comment: I meant just put the common markup outside the tab control completely. If it's common to all, it wouldn't make sense for it to be part of the the tab control.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could add the commom content in a single div and then before invoking the tab plugin, just add that common markup to each of the content blocks. Something like this:

Markup:

```
<div id="commonContent">
    <p>Some common stuff</p>
</div>

<ul id="tabNav">
     <li><a href="#tabContent1">Tab1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabContent2">Tab2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabContent3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabContent1" class="tabContent">
    <p>Content 1</p>
</div>
<div id="tabContent2" class="tabContent">
    <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabContent3" class="tabContent">
    <p>Content 3</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#commonContent').hide().appendTo($('.tabContent'));
            $('#tabNav').tabs();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Not tested, just giving the idea.

Comment: +1 for an interesting approach but it still duplicates the content... I like my current solution better where I am placing the content outside of the tabs and then adding negative margin.

Comment: True, it does duplicate, but only at the DOM level, not in markup. Your approach is certainly more economical in a resource-utilization sense. Thanks for the +1. Cheers!